setAngles() moves the arm and then returns to original position
I am using setAngles() (http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/motion/control-joint-api.html#ALMotionProxy::setAngles__AL::ALValueCR.AL::ALValueCR.floatCR) as follows:
self._motionProxy.setAngles("RArm", [head_yaw - 7 / 180 * np.pi, head_pitch, -0.25, 0.95 , 0.9, 0.05], 0.2))

The arm moves toward the mentioned angles but then returns to the initial position, my question is how to keep the arm at the target angles specified at the above function call?
Noting a blocking call function such as angleInterpolation() does the same as setAngles() where the arm returns to their origins.
